# How to view and set offsets.retention.minutes using kafka-configs

Tags: apache-kafka

From the documentation, this is a broker config, but details are thin.

1) What is the correct way to set this to indefinite?  If I do, will I still be able to delete consumer groups and their associated offsets manually?

2) Can I set individual consumer groups to have differing retention?

3) How do I view the retention globally, or for a specific consumer group?  Can I view this and get a number even if I have not set this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) mention that the valid values for `offsets.retention.minutes` are

> [1,...]

which means that you cannot set `offsets.retention.minutes=-1` but you can set it to a fairly large integer in order to keep the offsets for a long period.

2) I would assume that you are asking whether you can set different values for `offsets.retention.minutes` on a topic level; As far as I know, this is not possible. You can only modify this configuration on a broker level, i.e. inside `server.properties` file.

**EDIT:** 
I am afraid that you cannot avoid a rolling restart as you cannot change `offsets.retention.minutes` using `kafka-configs.sh`;

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 --alter --add-config offsets.retention.minutes=200800

Error while executing config command requirement failed: Unknown Dynamic Configuration 'retention.minutes'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Unknown Dynamic Configuration 'retention.minutes'.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$$anonfun$kafka$server$DynamicConfig$$validate$1.apply(DynamicConfig.scala:101)
        at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$$anonfun$kafka$server$DynamicConfig$$validate$1.apply(DynamicConfig.scala:100)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$.kafka$server$DynamicConfig$$validate(DynamicConfig.scala:100)
        at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$Broker$.validate(DynamicConfig.scala:59)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.changeBrokerConfig(AdminUtils.scala:555)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:105)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:68)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

3) Since this is a configuration on the broker level, you can view the value in `server.properties` file or from your broker's log files. For example,

```
 grep offsets.retention.minutes /path/to/your/kafka-broker.log
```

Note that even if you haven't configured `offsets.retention.minutes`, its value defaults to `10080`.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot afford a rolling restart at the moment.  I am really looking for a way to set the global value with kafka-configs.sh; if it has to be global that's fine.  It is just not obvious to me what the form of the command would be.

Comment: @SourceSimian I am afraid you cannot avoid a rolling restart. See my updated answer.

Comment: This does seem to be the case; I did a rolling restart with offsets.retention.minutes=2147483647 in the .properties file.  Time will tell if it has taken affect or the default (for my version) of 1 day is still in place.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay-- adjusting offsets.retention.minutes worked well.